# Javascript on tabletPC issue

Tags: javascript, tablet

I have 3 buttons on a webApplication and every time the user clicks on a button it changes to red, while the other two buttons become gray. I am using this piece of code to doing that:

```
    function toogleButton(b) {

    document.getElementById("internal").setAttribute("class", "icon-home span2");
    document.getElementById("external").setAttribute("class", "icon-target span2");
    document.getElementById("unknown").setAttribute("class", "icon-help-2 span2");
    var extraClass = " bg-color-red fg-color-white"
    document.getElementById(b.id).setAttribute("class", document.getElementById(b.id).getAttribute("class") + extraClass);        
}
```

This works fine on every browser in a desktop pc, but when I run it from a tablet (android) the buttons not change their colors.
Actually when a turn the tablet (from landscape to portair or vise versa) the new refreshed page has the new colors of the buttons but it's not working when a press that buttons.
I supposes that the problem is caused by the browser (android chrome) but the same issue happens with the dolphin browser too.

Is there any solution on that?

Comment: Try to use `document.getElementById("internal").className = 'icon-home span2'` instead of `setAttribute`

Comment: Thank you Serjio for the respond. Actually, I already have tried to use the className, but the behavior was exactly the same.